# Где хранить корзину товаров?

Tags: php

Вопрос прост. В сессии или в куках? Или может ещё где? Кто из Вас как пишет модули корзины?  Где Вы её храните?

Comment: Я не спец, но мне кажется, куки могут быть отключены или заблокированы файрволом, так что сессия выглядит предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно так: для неавторизованных пользователей данные хранятся в сессии, для авторизованных уже в БД.

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве реализаций корзину хранят в сессиях.
На мой взгляд это правильно. Во первых можно выбрать способ хранения сессиий как в базе данных так и в куках. Сессия как и корзина привязана к текущему сеансу данного пользователя.